# Web page parsing basics

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

everyone.

I need to parse web page, that is result of search request. I write Python script. So I need to fake search button click. So here's my question:

How can I find what script is run when the button is clicked?
The button code is (as I found in page inspection in Chrome):

```
<div class="submit button" data-ember-action="2">Search</div>
```

I feel that I should read more. I'll be grateful for ideas what direction to dig for.

The second is who to get script output. But, perhaps, the answer for the first question will be the answer for both

Comment: You'll have to look at the JavaScript to find something that is setting up a `click` event for the element that this submit "button" is for.

Comment: As Scott Marcus says: this is way beyond parsing HTML. This is dissecting an JavaScript application. Python only grabs the HTML, not the application wiring.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Chrome's Developer Tools/Inspector to set a breakpoint that listens for any click.  Once you set that breakpoint, you can click the button in Google Chrome and get more insight.

Here is a [link](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/chrome-devtools) that can show you how to get to the Google Chrome Developer Tools/Inspector (AKA DevTools).

Once you have the DevTools open, Click on the `Sources` tab near the top, then expand the `Event Listener Breakpoints` accordion.  Next, you can expand the `Mouse` accordion and activate the `click` event listener breakpoint by checking the box next to it.

After that, you can go back to the web page and click the button to stop the application in its tracks.  From there you can use the debugger to step through the code and see more information about the application.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to run the JS for that, not just read the page code.

So use something like Spalsh: https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ for javascript rendering. Then you can inspect the JS events more like you did in Chrome.

For a real Chrome inspection experience use headless Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome